# How to maximize element on all available area

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have 5 columns and 3 rows in grid. I was created Button and need to fill Column 1, Row 1 area with this button. What I should to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` on the Button to be `Stretch` so that the button will fill up the grid cell:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Button's height and width to the height and width of Grid's `Row1` and `Column1` respectively. As the following code,

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row1"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Column1}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=Row1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'll check it)